# guizero TextBox Append - Text not visible

Tags: python

I am using guizero to create a simple UI on a Python script on a Raspberry Pi 3. It is working though i'm having issues with the TextBox append() method.

The sample code illustrates the problem. It creates a 3 line TextBox with a scrollbar, however, when i use the append() method to add new lines i must scroll to see them.

How do i get the TextBox to automatically scroll to the bottom to show the last written text?

Help!

```
from guizero import App, TextBox, PushButton

def append():
    txtboxTest.append('Appended Text Not Visible Without Scrolling')

app = App(title="Test")
txtboxTest = TextBox(app, width=300, height=3, multiline=True, scrollbar=True, text="1\n2\n3")
appendbutton = PushButton(app, command=append, text="Append")

app.display()
```

Comment: *I need somebody... Help! Not just anybody...* Oh, sorry. Your phrasing made me think of that song. ;)

Comment: Looks like `txtboxTest.tk.see('end')` after each append might work - don't have guizero installed to test this.

Comment: @jasonharper Thankyou that worked! Can you answer so i can accept?